# How to keep PSFTP from closing the window?

Tags: putty, sftp, psftp

When I'm using PSFTP, if I let the connection timeout, the server will automatically close the connection. When this happens, any key press will cause the PSFTP window to close. Is there a way to change this setting? I'd like to just drop back to the main SFTP command prompt, so that I can type "open sitename.com" again, rather than having to go and launch PSFTP all over again. I know that when connecting through SSH using Putty, there is an option to keep the window open after the connection closes, but that setting in Putty doesn't seem to be picked up by PSFTP. Is there some kind of config option for this?